# EF Change Tracker: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm getting an error when I loop through a collection. I'm not changing the list at any point, but it gives me the following "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. Following code shows the method that I have this Parallel.Foreach.

```
public void DownloadImages()
        {
            IList<Vehicle> vehicles = _repository.Retrieve().ToList();
            Parallel.ForEach(vehicles, vehicle =>
            {
                IList<VehiclePhoto> vehiclePhotos =
                    vehicle.VehiclePhotos.Where(x => x.ImageStatus == ImageStatus.Inactive).ToList();
                if (vehiclePhotos.Count > 0)
                {
                    Parallel.ForEach(vehiclePhotos, photo =>
                    {
                        using (var client = new WebClient())
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                string fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + ".png";
                                string filePath = _imagePath + "\\" + fileName;
                                client.DownloadFile(photo.ImageUrl, filePath);
                                photo.FileName = fileName;
                                photo.ImageStatus = ImageStatus.Active;
                            }
                            catch (Exception)
                            {
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    _repository.Save(vehicle);
                }
            });
        }
```

This happens when _repository.Save(vehicle) is called. Following code will show the save changes method. base.SaveChanges(); is the place where error get raised.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            DateTime nowAuditDate = DateTime.Now;
            IEnumerable<System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry<DomainEntity>> changeSet = ChangeTracker.Entries<DomainEntity>();
            if (changeSet != null)
            {
                foreach (System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry<DomainEntity> entry in changeSet)
                {
                    switch (entry.State)
                    {
                        case EntityState.Added:
                            entry.Entity.Created = nowAuditDate;
                            entry.Entity.Modified = nowAuditDate;
                            break;
                        case EntityState.Modified:
                            entry.Entity.Modified = nowAuditDate;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Any ideas on this?

**EDITED:**
I was trying to fix this above mentioned error and changed few code lines in DownloadImages method. Those changes are as follows:

Instead of

```
IList<Vehicle> vehicles = _repository.Retrieve().ToList();
```

I used var

```
var vehicles = _repository.Retrieve().AsParallel();
```

Instead of

```
IList<VehiclePhoto> vehiclePhotos =
                        vehicle.VehiclePhotos.Where(x => x.ImageStatus == ImageStatus.Inactive).ToList();
```

I used var

```
var  vehiclePhotos =
                            vehicle.VehiclePhotos.Where(x => x.ImageStatus == ImageStatus.Inactive).AsParallel();
```

When I tried to run the code again. It gave me a different error: Error is as follows:

In the header it says

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException
```

But in the innerException

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException
```

**ExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.  The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are iterating over `vehicles` and the code inside the loop is changing the elements of the enumeration `vehicles`. Also, looping through `vehiclePhotos` and changing the elements of it.

I usually solve this by using an explicit `for` loop, i.e.:

```
for(var i = 0; i < vehicles.Count; i++)
{
    var vehicle = vehicles.ElementAt(i);

    // process vehicle
}
```

However, if you need to use `Parallel.ForEach`, you could try creating an array of integers with length of `vehicles.Count`, iterate over that and use it as index for `vehicles`.

Comment: Recently we had the same issue when tried to improve check required documents of our CRM accounts operation (runs nightly for all our accounts), unfortunately had no luck with enumerating our list to array (accounts.ToArray()) and going thru it in Parallel.For. Any ideas?

Comment: `account.ToArray()` would just make an array of references to the exact same objects as in your initial collection. It would not make a copy of each object. So, you would have the same problem if elements of the array are changing. Try the trick with creating an array of indexes and iterate over those, accessing elements of your collection using the index, i.e. `accounts[i].DoSomething()`.