# EF changetracker modified entries throwing collection modified error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I have a Windows desktop app with EF using a `dbcontext` and the change tracker. I am able to modify certain records to update datetime and modifiedby userid by iterating over a collection.

While it worked for some entries, a few other entries were throwing this error

> System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

The code I have is below and it compiles fine

```
 var changeSet = this.ChangeTracker.Entries();

 foreach (var entry in changeSet)
 {
     if (entry.State == EntityState.Added || entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
     {                   
         if (entry.Entity is IAuditableEntity entity)
         {
             entry.Entity.ModifieDate = Now;
             entry.Entity.ModifiedById = userId;//guid
         }
     }
}

// ModifiedById has a foreign key reference to Users table -> id field
// IAuditableEntity has ModifiedById and ModifiedDate fields
```

I tried converting to list but it throws an error it cannot convert to list. it worked for some models in the "this" context . The error was thrown only for one model.

Update:

copying the entries to a list and updating objects in the list does the job and there is no error. But I am wondering why it worked for few and not for others when I used `this.ChangeTracker.Entries()` with for each.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo

Comment: Possible answer to your updated question [EF Change Tracker: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449962/ef-change-tracker-collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execut).